# How to set variables in While Loop in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, while-loop, cursor

I am trying to use while loop instead of CURSOR in SQL SERVER. I am trying to select TOP 1 in while and set them to the variables like below. It doesnt let me set the variables in while loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
WHILE (
        SELECT TOP 1 @WAOR_CODE = WAOR_.WAOR_CODE
                   , @WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID = WAOD_.WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID
        FROM #wmsorder
    )
BEGIN
    SELECT @WAOR_CODE
         , @WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID

    DELETE TOP (1) #wmsorder
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option:

```
WHILE EXISTS(select 1 FROM #wmsorder)
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP (1)
    FROM #wmsorder
END
```

However, deleting all records from a table one by one might be a performance hell. You might want to consider using `TRUNCATE TABLE` instead:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE #wmsorder
```

Also, note that each delete is written to the database log, while truncate table doesn't get written to the log at all.

Testing with a temporary table containing 100,000 rows, deleting the rows one by one took me 9 seconds, while truncate table completed immediately:

```
-- create and populate sample table
SELECT TOP 100000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number
    INTO #wmsorder
    FROM sys.objects s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2

    -- delete rows one by one
    WHILE EXISTS(select 1 FROM #wmsorder)
    BEGIN
        DELETE TOP (1)
        FROM #wmsorder
    END

-- clean up
DROP TABLE #wmsorder



-- create and populate sample table
SELECT TOP 100000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number
    INTO #wmsorder
    FROM sys.objects s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2

-- truncate the table
TRUNCATE TABLE #wmsorder

-- clean up
DROP TABLE #wmsorder
```

Comment: ı am deleting rows one by one becuase I am trying to get rid of the rows that I used.

Comment: I see. in that case, you might want to re-think the entire script. you might find a set based way of doing whatever it is you do with this data instead of consuming the rows one by one.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (a INT PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES (1), (2), (3)
```

Variant #1:

```
label:
    DELETE TOP(1)
    FROM @t
    OUTPUT DELETED.a
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    GOTO label
```

Variant #2:

```
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT != 0
    DELETE TOP(1)
    FROM @t
    OUTPUT DELETED.a
```

Variant #3:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE(a INT)

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT != 0 BEGIN

    DELETE FROM @a

    DELETE TOP(1)
    FROM @t
    OUTPUT DELETED.a INTO @a

    SELECT * FROM @a

END
```

Comment: is this the fastest? I never thought of this method

Comment: @ayilmaz, iterative processing is always slow

Answer (score 0):

> See the below code. I just corrected the SQL statements shared by you

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #wmsorder)
            BREAK
        SELECT TOP 1 @WAOR_CODE = WAOR_.WAOR_CODE
            ,@WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID = WAOD_.WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID
        FROM #wmsorder WAOR_

        SELECT @WAOR_CODE
        ,@WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID

        DELETE #wmsorder WHERE WAOR_CODE = @WAOR_CODE AND WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID = @WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID
END
```

> But as Zohar Peled mentioned, it will be a pain to the engine if you are deleting the records one by one from a table. So below I have shared another query, through this even you can track the records before deleting from the table

```
DECLARE @TableVar AS TABLE (WAOR_CODE VARCHAR(100), WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID VARCHAR(100))
    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
            SELECT TOP 1 @WAOR_CODE = WAOR_.WAOR_CODE
                ,@WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID = WAOD_.WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID
            FROM #wmsorder WAOR_
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TableVar t WHERE t.WAOR_CODE = WAOR_.WAOR_CODE AND t.WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID = WAOR_.WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID)
            IF @WAOR_CODE IS NULL AND @WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID IS NULL
                BREAK

            INSERT INTO @TableVar
            (WAOR_CODE, WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID)
            SELECT @WAOR_CODE
            ,@WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID
    END
DELETE #wmsorder WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TableVar t WHERE t.WAOR_CODE = #wmsorder.WAOR_CODE AND t.WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID = #wmsorder.WAOD_INVENTORYITEMID)
```

> Sorry I did not test the second code. Please forgive me if it breaks something. But I am pretty sure it may require a small repair to make this query functional. All the best.